# How to loop through a list box?

Tags: c#, listbox, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to loop through a list box text instead of having to select a line, but I am unsure on how to do so.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").SetAttribute("value", listBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Make it clearer that this is about a HtmlElement from a WebControl.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foreach(var item in listbox1.Items)
{
//Do somethings
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)